# Notifications banners on Do Not Disturb in iOS 15

Tags: ios, notifications, do-not-disturb

How can I see notifications banners and sounds while I using Do Not Disturb on iOS 15.
In iOS 14 and lower the notifications silence is only while the phone is locked.
Dose it possible to set it on iOS 15 too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option currently does not exist (anymore) as of iOS 15.0

[Article on Macrumors](https://www.macrumors.com/2021/09/21/ios-15-do-not-disturb-feature-removed/)